# Multistore redirect from https://old.dk to https://new.dk

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I have 2 shops, with 90% the same products. Both shops are in the same Magento 1.9 Multi Store setup.
Now I want to "shut down" the old shop and redirect all visits from the old shop to the new shop.

As I understand all Multi store shops share the same .htaccess - so how do I write a rewrite/redirect that only redirects from https://old.dk to https://new.dk?

The URLs are almost all the same except the domain of course.

Can anybody help a novice?